# Angular - How to apply children RouterActiveLink class?

Tags: angular

I have Children Routing under Parent Routing. Children routing works fine. Unfortunately, the tabs of children are not getting active class.

1. Is that something I am missing to add?
2. Is it required to do addition coding for children routes like adding directives?

Parent:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li routerLink="/Home" routerLinkActive="active"><a>HOME</a></li>
    <li routerLink="/Courses" routerLinkActive="active"><a>COURSES</a></li>
    <li routerLink="/Resources" routerLinkActive="active"><a>RESOURCES</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section>  
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

Children: Under Courses Link

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li [routerLink]="['JavaScript']" routerActiveLink="active">
      <a>JavaScript</a>
    </li>
    <li [routerLink]="['Java']" routerActiveLink="active">
      <a>Java</a></li>
    <li routerLink="DotNet" routerActiveLink="active">
      <a>DotNet</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div> 
</div>
```

When I click on Parent Link, routerActiveLink works fine. But when I click on Children(Courses) links, active link doesn't work properly!

For Parent & Course Components CSS files, I have created CSS property as

```
.active a{background: yellow;color:pink;}
```

Comment: Try `<li routerLink="/JavaScript" routerActiveLink="active">`

Comment: <li [routerLink]="['/JavaScript']" routerActiveLink="active">
      <a>JavaScript</a>
    </li>
The router stops responding, I already tried it.  

    <li [routerLink]="['JavaScript']" routerActiveLink="active" >
      <a>JavaScript</a>
     </li>
Then only it works.

Comment: If I'm correct you only have to at `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` on the app.component and no where else.

Comment: I have <router-outlet></router-outlet> on both parent and children, after UL tags. 

I have no issues, it routes to specific routes either parent or children. Only issue is class applying to parent only, not to active child!

    {
      path: 'Courses',
      component: COURSESComponent,
      children: [
        {path: 'JavaScript', component:JAVASCRIPTComponent},
        {path: 'Java', component:JAVAComponent},
        {path: 'DotNet', component:DOTNETComponent}
      ]
    },

Comment: How you apply the css global?

Comment: No, I am apply to individual component. Like App.component has its own css, where I apply .active a 

For courses Component its own css, where I apply .active a

But I tried global, which doesn't work now for parent or children routes.

Comment: Sorry, found the issue, silly of me. I did a typo while learning & experimenting children and parameter routes. 

The Children route routerActiveLink -> routerLinkActive. 

As they parent and child were in separate files, which I missed to see this typo.

Comment: Glad it's fixed now

Comment: @Swoox Thanks for your time. :)